# Flutter project apk doesn't work properly on real device, but works well on emulator

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, apk, flutter-apk

I have problem about flutter apk. I work on project that given to me from company. I prepared a lot of pages and in the end i decided to build apk and see how it seems on real device. First of all,i wanna say that everything is ok on emulator. Paddings,texts and etc. But when I open apk on real device, everything is mess. Paddings not working,a lot of texts not appear and etc. I tried to open apk on other device. First time I open, fortunately everything was ok, all padding and other things. But I exited and open again,so same thing,same problem. By the way, in AndroidManifest.xml file, i added internet permission. To see problem exactly, i put here 2 images of one page: [with no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqT6s.jpg) , [with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrm5N.jpg). Btw i use VSCode.

I tried to open apk on other device. First time I open, fortunately everything was ok, all padding and other things. But I exited and open again,so same thing,same problem.

Comment: I assume you run debug mode on emulator and run released APK on real device. To find out the problem try the other 2 cases: run debug mode on real device and run released APK on emulator. See which case has the same error.

Comment: How can i run released apk on emulator? For example, downloading telegram on emulator and download apk from there?

Comment: First build the apk by ```flutter build apk``` command then ```flutter install``` when emulator is selected.

Comment: For Android you can also run `flutter run --release` to run on release mode

Comment: Guys,i tried. First time i run command `flutter run --release` everything was ok. Second time,same problem.

Comment: you can drag the APK file to the emulator to install

Comment: I wonder if your project use some kind of sizing package? like flutter_screenutil maybe?

Comment: I also try to run in debug mode on my phone via usb. It is working with no problem. Everything is ok. Just i see some on debug console : 
`E/LB      (18753): fail to open file: No such file or directory
D/DecorView[](18753): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
W/MirrorManager(18753): this model don't Support`

Comment: yes i use flutter_screenutil package

Comment: Try to see if flutter_screenutil is the problem. Maybe try removing screenutil usage in one screen first (the one that has the issue) and see if it solves the problem. For example like changing `width: 20.h` to `width: 20`

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code or whatever you use to define your layout.